# Command to format a raw floppy disk image with FAT12?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, disk-format, floppy

I'm new to OS Development, and I want to format a 1.44MB floppy image with the FAT12 file system. I created the disk using `dd if=/dev/zero of=<my image> bs=512 count=2880`, so it's just a raw image filled with zeros. Next, I wanted to create the file system. The guy in the tutorial used `mkfs.fat12`, but I'm working on MacOS.

The only command I've found for formatting disks there is `newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 <my image>`.

But that commands just prints an error: `newfs_msdos: Inappropriate ioctl for device: build/disk2.img: Cannot get partition offset`

I've also found `diskutil eraseDisk`, but that only works for a mounted device, not for disk images, and I can't mount a disk image if it has no working file system.

I'd be thankful if someone knows a command that works for floppy images, or if someone can tell me what triggered this error and how I can avoid it.

How can I tell the command that there is no partitions or offsets, and I just want to format the whole disk?

Comment: I’m curious what hardware is involved? Which floppy drive, connected how to which Mac?

Comment: Does the answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338718/creating-bootable-freedos-dos-floppy-diskette-img-file-for-v86-on-osx help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating bootable FreeDOS DOS floppy diskette IMG file for V86 on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338718/creating-bootable-freedos-dos-floppy-diskette-img-file-for-v86-on-osx)

Comment: If you have an answer, then please post it as an answer and **not** as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, final solution here that worked for me:

Create an image with a command like that (or whatever you used to create your disk image):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2880
```

Then attach it to:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount disk.img
```

That commands print the attached path, like `/dev/disk4`. Then you can format that path:

```
newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 disk4
```

(it's important to write e.g. "disk4", not "/dev/disk4")

And then finally detach the image:

```
hdiutil detach disk4
```

That solution worked on my Mac Mini M1, MacOS Somona 14.0

Comment: You can use `disk4`, `rdisk4` or `/dev/rdisk4` as the device for the `newfs_msdos` command. In other words, the `newfs_msdos` command expects a character special file, which is unbuffered.  Specifying the block special file `/dev/disk4`, which is buffered, will generate a warning message.

Answer (score 2):

For a quicker read, I moved the conclusion section to the top of this answer.

### Conclusion

The OP should use the commands given in Case 2 to format the image. However, using the commands given in Case 1 will probably correctly format the image when using OS X 10.6.8 through macOS 13.3.1 on an Intel Mac.

---

### Introduction

I cannot reproduce your problem. In other words, I am not able to not format the image.

I test using the following machines

- Snow Leopard virtual machine with a drive sector size of 512 bytes.
- Monterey virtual machine with a drive sector size of 512 bytes.
- Venture 2018 Mac mini with a drive sector size of 4096 bytes.

### Case 1

Based on the question, I executed the following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=x.img bs=512 count=2880
newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 ./x.img
```

The output is given below.

```
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % dd if=/dev/zero of=x.img bs=512 count=2880
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes transferred in 0.011958 secs (123311591 bytes/sec)
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 ./x.img
newfs_msdos: warning: ./x.img is not a character device
ioctl(DKIOCGETPHYSICALBLOCKSIZE) not supported
./x.img: 5726 sectors in 2863 FAT12 clusters (1024 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=2 res=1 nft=2 rde=240 sec=5760 mid=0xf0 spf=9 spt=36 hds=2 hid=0 drv=0x00
```

An error message was generated because the sector (block) size could not be determined from the image file `x.img`. However, output shows a `bps` (bytes per sector) value of 512 was used as a default value.

### Case 2

I executed the following commands. Here, the command `hdiutil attach` was used to attach a disk image as a device. The identifier `disk7` was determined from the output of this command.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=y.img bs=512 count=2880
hdiutil attach -nomount y.img
newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 disk7
hdiutil detach disk7
```

The output is given below.

```
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % dd if=/dev/zero of=y.img bs=512 count=2880
2880+0 records in
2880+0 records out
1474560 bytes transferred in 0.012780 secs (115380282 bytes/sec)
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % hdiutil attach -nomount y.img
/dev/disk7                                              
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % newfs_msdos -f 2880 -F 12 disk7
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk7: 5726 sectors in 2863 FAT12 clusters (1024 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=2 res=1 nft=2 rde=240 sec=5760 mid=0xf0 spf=9 spt=36 hds=2 hid=0 drv=0x00
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % hdiutil detach disk7           
"disk7" ejected.
```

Here no error messages were generated since the `bps` value could be determined to be 512.

### Comparison of Case 1 and Case 2

I entered the following commands to compare the two image files.

```
hexdump -C x.img >x.lst
hexdump -C y.img >y.lst
diff x.lst y.lst
```

The output is given below.

```
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % hexdump -C x.img >x.lst
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % hexdump -C y.img >y.lst
davidanderson@Lobster Desktop % diff x.lst y.lst
3c3
< 00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 29 12  0d c4 37 4e 4f 20 4e 41  |......)...7NO NA|
---
> 00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 29 15  0d c9 37 4e 4f 20 4e 41  |......)...7NO NA|
```

The difference between the two files is at byte offsets 0x27 and 0x29. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Boot_Sector), bytes at offsets 0x27 through 0x2A contain the disk serial number, which is expected to be different between FAT12 formatted images.

Comment: Ok, I tried the first way again, which was also like how I tried to do it, and it still gives the same error. (I'm working on a real Mac with Sonoma 14.0, maybe it depends on the version)Somehow the command doesn't like disk images, but **the second way worked for me**. I didn't know the way to attach the image without mounting the file system, thank you for that.

Comment: axolotlKing0722: Including the Mac model/year and the version of OS X/macOS usually is helpful when posting questions and answers. For example, I still do not know whether your Mac is Intel or Apple Silicon.

Comment: Running case 1 on Sonoma 14.1/M1 gives `newfs_msdos: Inappropriate ioctl for device: ./x.img: Cannot get partition offset`. Case 2 works fine.

Comment: @nohillside yeah, excatly that was my problem